# Here Maps Navigate restarts Navigation on page change

Tags: flutter, dart, heremaps

I have a problem with my **Here Maps Navigation**. I can start the navigation on my flutter app but every time I **open another page on the app and come back to the navigation page, it restarts the navigation**. It tries to get the current location again, takes a lot of time to do that, and shows the default "invalid" map page. I want the navigation to **save it's current state even if I change the view to another page** on my app and come back to navigating. Is there a way to do this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve it by saving the state of my Flutter pages. I used the `PageView` widget for the main.dart's scaffold body and `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on the pages I wanted to save the states of. You can check this YouTube video for how to implement this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGe45NikVqE